Recurrence $T(n) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(k) + 1)$
I'm trying to solve the recurrence:
$$T(n) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(k) + 1) \tag{1}$$
I asked this same question here and Robert gave a very useful hint. I'm very close to the solution, but there is one little piece that just isn't fitting in. I've been poring over it for hours and hope someone can help me. Apologies in advance for the obvious thing I'm missing.
First, we use Robert's hint and define:
$$S(n) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n T(n)$$
This implies $T(n) = S(n)-S(n-1)$. Substituting in equation (1) we get,
$$S(n)-S(n-1) = 2S(n-1)+2(n-1)$$
$$=> S(n) = 3S(n-1)+2(n-1) \tag{2}$$
I somehow found the form that satisfies this recurrence (with help from some AIs): $S(n) = \frac{1}{2}3^{n+1}-n+c$.
To verify, substitute into the RHS of equation (2):
$$RHS = 3\left(\frac{1}{2}3^{n}-(n-1)+c\right)+2(n-1)=\frac{1}{2}3^{n+1}-n+(1+3c)$$
This is satisfied by $c=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Now that we have $S(n)$, let's get $T(n) = S(n)-S(n-1)$. This gives us:
$$T(n) = \left(\frac{1}{2}3^{n+1}-n-\frac{1}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}3^{n}-(n-1)-\frac{1}{2}\right) = 3^n-1$$.
Now I want to verify this by substituting into equation (1). I get:
$$3^n-1 = 2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} (3^k - 1 + 1) = 2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} 3^k$$
And now, the expression on the right is $ (3^n-3)$ instead of the expected $3^n-1$.
Where am I going wrong?

Here's a snake-oil approach.  Let $f(z)$ be the ordinary generating function of the sequence $\{T(n)\}_{n \ge 1}$.  Then
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty T(n) z^n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(k) + 1)\right) z^n \\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k) z^n + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} z^n \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty T(k) \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty z^n + 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)z^n \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty T(k) \frac{z^{k+1}}{1-z} + 2 \frac{z^2}{(1-z)^2} \\
&= \frac{2z}{1-z} \sum_{k=1}^\infty T(k) z^k + \frac{2z^2}{(1-z)^2} \\
&= \frac{2z}{1-z} f(z) + \frac{2z^2}{(1-z)^2}.
\end{align}
Solving for $f(z)$ yields
\begin{align}
f(z) 
&= \frac{2z^2}{1-4z+3z^2} \\ 
&= \frac{2}{3} - \frac{1}{1-z} + \frac{1/3}{1-3z} \\ 
&= \frac{2}{3} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3z)^n \\
&= \frac{2}{3} - \left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n\right) + \frac{1}{3}\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (3z)^n \right)\\
&= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^n + \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (3z)^n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (3^{n-1}-1) z^n,
\end{align}
which immediately implies that
$$T(n) = 3^{n-1} - 1.$$

Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I wonder why it's called snake oil.

@RohitPandey Wilf (p.118) compares the method to "snake oil" (a purported cure for everything), because of its surprisingly high success rate for evaluating combinatorial sums.

I have a question. It was looking like there are multiple solutions depending on the initial conditions. With the one you got corresponding to $T(1)=0$. In this solution, that boundary condition wasn't used explicitly. Does that make this solution ($3^{n-1}-1$) somehow more "natural"?

$T(1)=0$ is implied by the recurrence relation because empty sums are $0$.  I used this recurrence even for $n=1$ to get from the first line to the second line.

Note that Equation (1) holds for $n\geq2$. Hence your solution, $T(n)=3^n-1$ holds for $n\geq2$. To validate,
\begin{align*}
  3^n-1 &= T(n) \\
  &= 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} [T(k)+1] \\
  &= 2T(1) + 2 \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} T(k) + 2(n-1) \\
  &= 2T(1) + 2 \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} (3^k-1) + 2(n-1) \\
  &= 2T(1) + 2 \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} 3^k + 2 \\
  &= 2T(1) + 9 (3^{n-2}-1) + 2 \\
  &= 2T(1) + 3^n - 7 . 
\end{align*}
So we see that $T(1)=3$. In conclusion,
$$ T(1)=3 , \quad T(n)=3^n-1 (n\geq2) $$
In addition, $S(n)$ should have some indefiniteness. Equation (2) can be transformed
$$ S(n)+n+\frac{1}{2} = 3 \left[ S(n-1) + (n-1) + \frac{1}{2} \right] \quad (n\geq2) . $$
It's easy to see
$$ S(n)+n+\frac{1}{2} = 3^{n-2} \left[ S(2) + 2 + \frac{1}{2} \right]
= 3^{n-2} \left[ S(2) + \frac{5}{2} \right] . $$
Hence we have
$$ S(n) = 3^{n-2} \left[ S(2) + \frac{5}{2} \right] - n - \frac{1}{2} 
\quad (n\geq2) . $$
This yields more general solution.

Sorry, don't see how this makes the equation align and make sense.

I edited my answer. Your solution is a case $S(2)=11$.

If you compute the first terms of the sequence $(T(n))=(0,0,2,8,26,80,\dots)$ you see that $(T(n)+1)=(1,1,3,9,27,\dots)$. This immediately gives the conjecture $T(n)+1=3^{n-1}$ for  $n \geq 1$ which is easily verified.

For an equation of ths form
$T(n) 
= a \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k)+f(n)
$
(yours is
$a=2, f(n)=2(n-1)$)
$\begin{array}\\
T(n+1)
&= a \sum_{k=1}^{n} T(k)+f(n+1)\\
&= a \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k)+aT(n)+f(n+1)\\
&= T(n)-f(n)+aT(n)+f(n+1)\\
&= (a+1)T(n)+f(n+1)-f(n)\\
\end{array}
$
This can be solved in many ways.
This is my favorite.
$\begin{array}\\
T(n+1)
&= (a+1)T(n)+f(n+1)-f(n)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{T(n+1)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}
&= \dfrac{(a+1)T(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}+\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}\\
&= \dfrac{T(n)}{(a+1)^{n}}+\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}\\
\text{Letting}\\
U(n)
&=\dfrac{T(n)}{(a+1)^{n}}\\
U(n+1)
&=U(n)+\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}\\
\text{so}\\
U(n+1)-U(n)
&=\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$
Summing from
$n0$ to $m$
(where $n0$ is the initial index
that $T(n)$ is defined at),
$\begin{array}\\
U(m)-U(n0)
&=\sum_{n=n0}^{m-1}(U(n+1)-U(n))\\
&=\sum_{n=n0}^{m-1}\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}\\
\end{array}
$
so
$U(m)
=U(n0)+\sum_{n=n0}^{m-1}\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}
$
or
$\dfrac{T(m)}{(a+1)^{m}}
=\dfrac{T(n0)}{(a+1)^{n0}}+\sum_{n=n0}^{m-1}\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}
$
or
$\begin{array}\\
T(m)
&=T(n0)(a+1)^{m-n0}+(a+1)^m\sum_{n=n0}^{m-1}\dfrac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(a+1)^{n+1}}\\
&=T(n0)(a+1)^{m-n0}+\sum_{n=n0}^{m-1}(f(n+1)-f(n))(a+1)^{m-n-1}\\
&=T(n0)(a+1)^{m-n0}+\sum_{n=0}^{m-1-n0}(f(m-n)-f(m-n-1))(a+1)^{n}
\quad n \to m-1-n\\
\end{array}
$
If $f(n)$ is a polynomial,
the sum can be evaluated explicitly.
In your case,
$f(n)=2(n-1), n0=1$
so $f(n+1)-f(n)=2$
so, since $a=2$,
the sum is
$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{m-2}(f(m-n)-f(m-n-1))(a+1)^{n}
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{m-2}3^n\\
&=3^{m-1}-3\\
\end{array}
$
so
$T(m)
=T(1)3^{m-1}+3^{m-1}-3
=(T(1)+1)3^{m-1}-3
$.
(modulo any algebraic errors)

Thanks. Very helpful. There is a small error somewhere I think. You should have gotten -1 instead of -3.

Yep. My usual unforced error.

One of the solutions I got after torturing ChatGPT for 30 minutes was the following: $T(n) = 3^{n-1}-1$.
Even though its process for getting to this was obviously wrong (bugs in the Math), the solution itself works.
The boundary condition is: $T(1)=0$, which aligns well with the problem for which I was creating the recurrence. And the recurrence is satisfied without special casing for $T(1)$ (although still required for $T(0)$).
This is also mentioned in a comment by Johann.
And the $S(n)$ that results in that solution:
$$S(n) = \frac{2}{3} \cdot 3^{n-1} - n - \frac{1}{2}$$
